# Select record based on status if it exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table structure like below.

```
id,shipment no,status, date
1 ,     2     ,     I, 2013-12-12
2 ,     3     ,     I, 2013-12-12
3 ,     3     ,     S, 2013-12-12
```

I need to filter based on date. i am able to do that, but for a given shipmentno if 'S' status is there i need to take that record or else i need to take 'I' status record. How can i do this in 1 query?

Comment: trying using case statement !! `select id,status,date,
             case shipment when 'S' then id else 'I'end`

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(\`status\`, 'S', 'I') LIMIT 1` should do it

Comment: LEFT [OUTER] JOIN the table to itself and use COALESCE

Comment: @Hacker I would have accepted `Ctulhu` comment as answer.

Comment: Well, no. The OP obviously wants ALL shipments!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.shipmentNo, a.status, a.date 
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.shipmentNo, a.status, a.date 
      FROM shipment a ORDER BY a.shipmentNo, FIELD(a.status, 'S', 'I')
      WHERE a.date = '2013-12-12'
      ) A
GROUP BY a.shipmentNo
```

Comment: It is not garanteed that mysql will return data from the first row of groupped ones.

Comment: Not to mention, your query is functionally identical to much simplier `SELECT * FROM shipment WHERE date='2013-12-12' GROUP BY \`shipment no\` ORDER BY \`shipment no\`,FIELD(status, 'S', 'I')`

Comment: No it ain't - but only because of a quirk (i.e. undocumented behaviour) of MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry And when these two queries will yield different results?

Comment: @Strawberry I do believe you are able to do that yourself.

Comment: Yep. I believe I can.

Comment: What does FIELD function actually do? Does it search the column and it starts giving the index in the order we have given?

Comment: @Hacker Check the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field